# Java JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame Centering Issue

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I'm working with `JDesktopPane`'s and `JInternalFrame`'s and I'm having some difficulty centering the frames in the desktop. What I've found is that when I determine the center of the desktop using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, the position I get is the center of the desktop if the `JFrame` wasn't maximized. Is there a way to get the 'real' dimensions of the desktop?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. `JDesktop` doesn't have a concept of "scrollable", although it allows views to positioned outside it's viewable area, it doesn't provide a means by which you can access those frames.

Comment: MadProgrammer means `JDesktopPane` instead of `JDesktop` :)

Comment: @user1803551 Yeah, no one knows what I mean, least of all myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after several hours of debugging, I figured out what the problem was: The `JFrame` wasn't made visible until after I had finished adding/positioning everything, so it wasn't set to it's maximized size.

Comment: Which would have been easily fixed had you Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrated your problem, saving you several hours of joy and happiness...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I figured out what the problem was when I tried to make a runnable example and couldn't replicate the issue at first.